# How to improve my classification model?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have got a binary classification problem with large dataset

Also dataset is fairly balanced of 67% Class 0 , 33% Class 1.

My accuracy score is very less in test dataset as compared to train dataset which is clearly a case of Overfitting

[image]

Also my classification report is

[image]

How to improve my model?  I have tried undersampling , cross validation , lasso feature selection , etc.

Comment: The results are already much better than [last time](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/109028/64377), congrats! We would need more detail to help you: what kind of task are you doing? how many instances? how many features? which learning algorithm?

Comment: I have used random forest classifiers , extra tree classifiers for prediction. There are 55 features in my dataset with 1 mill records.

Answer (score 2):

I would empasize on more feature engineering like create more derived transformed features (log,interaction features (additive,division) etc.), trying out different bins, one-hot encoding, play with features based on business understanding etc.

Comment: Upvoted, very helpful keep up the good work...